# change bash IO buffer setting

Tags: linux, bash, io

I have code as followed:

```
mkfifo test.pipe
# execute another program at this point. it reads test.pipe(readonly), and falls asleep.
# the program will respond line by line.
exec 4>test.pipe
echo hello world >&4
```

But I found the program will not respond, because the `hello world` in fd `4` is not flushed. i think bash open this file using block buffer, so even though I have `\n` here, the message will not be flushed.

So my question is, how to make `4` not buffered or line buffered?

notice that I don't prefer

```
echo hello world! >test.pipe
```

since the program will read an eof, which is not my expectation.

UPDATE:

or any other way, i just don't want EOF on the program side happens too frequently(burst of extra check otherwise).

Comment: the `stdbuf` command couldn't help? (drawback - must include it to every output redirection)

Comment: @jm666 only for standard io? how to work with my requirement here?

Comment: `(echo hello world >&4)` should ensure that the message is flushed, but is a fairly large hammer (sub-shell) to fix a small nut.  I'm assuming the 'another program' is run in background or otherwise not preventing the `exec` and `echo` from executing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sure in the background.

Comment: I ran your code exactly "as is" and it works without a hitch, so probably the problem is elsewhere. by the way, the fifo is actually line buffered.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand the problem, because the following

```
mkfifo test.pipe

sed 's/.*/i am the sed>>&<</' < test.pipe &   #pipe reader in bg

exec 4>test.pipe

for i in {1..5}
do
echo "$i to pipe wihout NL sleeping 2 secs"
echo -n hello world $i >&4
sleep 2
echo "now the NL - and the sed responds"
echo >&4
sleep 0.5
echo =====
done
```

the `sed` responds immediatelly as get the `\n`.

Comment: oh really?! i looped over 1024 times with 8 bytes message to let the other side receive my data.

Comment: i start to think maybe the bash on my system is screwed.